# Git-tfs and spaces in Project name

Tags: git-tfs

What is the syntax to clone a TFS project in git-tfs when the project name has spaces? I have tried:

```
git-tfs.exe clone http://tfsint:8080/tfsint01/ "$/NPP UBI Dev/DEV1"
```

The system cannot find the file specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
git tfs clone http://tfsint:8080/tfsint01/ "$/NPP UBI Dev/DEV1"
```

So "git tfs" instead of "git-tfs.exe".

The error message you're getting is actually not referring to the project name. It seems to be caused by git-tfs not being able to locate git.exe. (It is git.cmd that is added to the path by default). [More information here](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/31).